# Default Routing to web api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

**In Web API default routing as below:**

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And now calls to different controllers can be made as below:

```
/api/contacts
/api/contacts/1
/api/products/gizmo1
```

I want to change it to map default url to a given controller:
e.g. If I make following

- ***/api***  it should respond as ***/api/contacts***
- ***/api/1***  it should respond as  ***/api/contacts/1***

What changes I should make to routing?

Cheers

Comment: you can add a route attribute on top of your contacts action something like this ...  [Route("")] now it will call this when you call only API

Comment: Seems [Route("")] works with web api 2.0, I am still using web api 1.0 as server has .net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

you need to have two routes in this case, like given below

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi1",
         routeTemplate: "api/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "contacts"}
         );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "contacts", id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
```